# Error while compiling css and js files using gulp

Tags: gulp

I am getting the below mentioned error and I am not able to figure out how to handle it. Versions of gulp, node and npm are mentioned below.  I don't know if it is node's version mismatch with that of gulp or something else but so far any help would be much appreciated.

```
gulp -v
CLI Version: 2.3.0
Local Version: 3.9.1

node -v
v6.10.3

npm -v
3.10.10

ERROR

C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\engine.io\build\server.js:173

    async handshake(transportName, req, closeConnection) {
          ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\engine.io\build\engine.io.js:5:18)
```

Comment: gulp can only run tasks. Please add what  gulp plugins you are using.

Comment: @connexo I am using Laravel-Elixir v5.0.0, bower 1.8.14,  Slick-Carousel 1.8.2, foundation-sites 6.3.1, motion-ui 2.0.3

Comment: You haven't mentioned a single gulp plugin.

Comment: @connexo I am new to this entire package thing. I am told that Laravel-Elixir is being used as a wrapper for Gulp and in gulpfile.js I've used elixir anonymous function; mix.sass, mix.styles, mix.scripts. Apart from that I've used elixir.config.sourcemaps=false;

Comment: `async handshake(transportName, req, closeConnection) {` should probably be `async function handshake(transportName, req, closeConnection) {`

Comment: @connexo just tried it, doesn't work. Same error.

Comment: Then your JS processor in the gulp stack probably either doesn't understand, or is not configured to understand, modern JS.

Comment: Should I upgrade gulp? I am anyhow using Jquery V2.2 so i don't think there should be a problem compiling the older version of Jquery by Gulp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for `async` functions was added in Node 7.6.0.

You are using Node 6.10.3.

You need to upgrade.

The oldest version of Node which is still supported (although only for a matter of weeks!) is version 12.

Upgrade to at least version 16.14.2 (the current long term support release).

Comment: Is the function keyword not required?

Comment: @connexo — Not for a method definition.

Comment: Ah okay, well the code shown doesn't make clear if it's a function definition inside an object / class.

Answer (score 0):

install version 8.11.1 and run :

```
npm install
npm install gulp bower --global
            
npm install node-sass@latest
npm uninstall laravel-elixir
npm uninstall session
npm install --save laravel-elixir
npm install --save session
gulp
```

after that it will work